# Unable to mount MySQL data volume to Kubernetes Minikube pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a dev environment with Kubernetes via Minikube. I successfully mounted the same volume to the same data dir on the same image with Docker for Mac, but I'm having trouble with Minikube.

Relevant files and logs:
`db-pod.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    name: msyql
  name: db
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mysqldev
      image: mysql/mysql-server:5.6.32
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          hostPort: 3306
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
          name: volumesnew
  volumes:
    - name: volumesnew
      hostPath:
        path: "/Users/eric/Volumes/mysql"
```

`kubectl get pods`:

```
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
db        0/1       Error     1          3s
```

`kubectl logs db`:

```
2016-08-29 20:05:55 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-08-29 20:05:55 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.32) starting as process 1 ...
2016-08-29 20:05:55 1 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
```

`kubectl describe pods db`:

```
Name:       db
Namespace:      default
Node:       minikubevm/10.0.2.15
Start Time:     Wed, 31 Aug 2016 07:48:39 -0700
Labels:     name=msyql
Status:     Running
IP:         172.17.0.3
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  mysqldev:
    Container ID:       docker://af0937edcd9aa00ebc278bc8be00bc37d60cbaa403c69f71bc1b378182569d3d
    Image:          mysql/mysql-server:5.6.32
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:0fb418d5a10c9632b7ace0f6e7f00ec2b8eb58a451ee77377954fedf6344abc5
    Port:           3306/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:        1
      Started:      Wed, 31 Aug 2016 07:48:42 -0700
      Finished:     Wed, 31 Aug 2016 07:48:43 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:      1
    Environment Variables:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:      test
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True
  Ready         False
  PodScheduled  True
Volumes:
  volumesnew:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /Users/eric/Volumes/newmysql
  default-token-il74e:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-il74e
QoS Tier:       BestEffort
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From            SubobjectPath           Type        Reason      Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----            -------------           --------        ------      -------
  7s        7s          1       {default-scheduler }                    Normal      Scheduled       Successfully assigned db to minikubevm
  6s        6s          1       {kubelet minikubevm}    spec.containers{mysqldev}       Normal      Created     Created container with docker id 568f9112dce0
  6s        6s          1       {kubelet minikubevm}    spec.containers{mysqldev}       Normal      Started     Started container with docker id 568f9112dce0
  6s        4s          2       {kubelet minikubevm}    spec.containers{mysqldev}       Normal      Pulled      Container image "mysql/mysql-server:5.6.32" already present on machine
  4s        4s          1       {kubelet minikubevm}    spec.containers{mysqldev}       Normal      Created     Created container with docker id af0937edcd9a
  4s        4s          1       {kubelet minikubevm}    spec.containers{mysqldev}       Normal      Started     Started container with docker id af0937edcd9a
  3s        2s          2       {kubelet minikubevm}    spec.containers{mysqldev}       Warning     BackOff     Back-off restarting failed docker container
  3s        2s          2       {kubelet minikubevm}                    Warning     FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "mysqldev" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=mysqldev pod=db_default(012d5178-6f8a-11e6-97e8-c2daf2e2520c)"
```

I was able to mount the data directory from the host to the container in a test directory, but I'm having trouble mounting to the MySQL data directory. Also, I tried to mount an empty directory to the container's data dir with the appropriate MySQL environment variables set, which in Docker for Mac allowed me to perform a SQL dump in the new dir, but I'm seeing the same errors in Minikube.

Any thought on what might be the cause, or if I'm not setting up my dev environment the preferred Kubernetes/Minikube way, please share your thoughts.

Comment: What vm driver are you using? xhyve?

Comment: @jimmi-dyson VirtualBox

Comment: I would have expected the the mysql logs to have more detail on what's causing it to exit. Can you increase logging for mysql somehow? Not sure. Also, can you share output of `kubectl describe pod <mysql_pod_name>` to see if there's anything interesting in there.

Comment: Ok, updated with `kubectl describe pods db` output. Not much to see there, from what I can tell. It's interesting that volume mounting IS WORKING in other directories. Even the same volume in a different path in the container. I'll look into getting more verbose msyql logs.

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this with the following:

```
echo "/Users -network 192.168.99.0 -mask 255.255.255.0 -alldirs -maproot=root:wheel" | sudo tee -a /etc/exports
sudo nfsd restart
minikube start
minikube ssh -- sudo umount /Users
minikube ssh -- sudo /usr/local/etc/init.d/nfs-client start
minikube ssh -- sudo mount 192.168.99.1:/Users /Users -o rw,async,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,proto=tcp
```

I am running Minikube in VirtualBox. I don't know if this will work with other VM drivers - xhyve, etc.

Reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2

EDIT: I should mention that this works for minikube v0.14.0.

Comment: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/

Answer (score 0):

**1. Mount the folder you want to share on your host, in minikube:**

```
minikube mount ./path/to/mySharedData:/mnt1/shared1
```

Don't close the terminal. That process needs to be running all the time for the folder to be accessible.

**2. Use that folder with hostPath:**

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysqldev
          image: mysql/mysql-server:5.6.32
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              hostPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
              name: my-volume
      volumes:
        - name: my-volume
          hostPath:
            path: "/mnt1/shared1"
```

**3. Writing access issue?**

In case you have a writing access issue, you might want to mount the volume with:

```
minikube mount ./path/to/mySharedData:/mnt1/shared1 --uid 10001 --gid 10001
```

Here, the volume mounted in minikube will have group id and user id 10001. This is the user id of Azure SQL Edge server inside the container.

I don't know which is the user id of mysql in your case. If you want to know, log into your container and type `id`, it will tell you the user id.